# Updating text file on the FTP server ?

Tags: c#, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I want to update the existing file on the server without loosing already saved data on the file. Currently If I try to write something. It overwrite on the file by removing previous data.

I am using following code.

```
       using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ftp.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (string value in row)
            {

                if (sb.Length > 0)
                    sb.Append(",");

                sb.Append(value);
            }
            sw.WriteLine(oldRecords.ToString() + sb.ToString());
            sw.Flush();
        }
```

how can I update file without loosing the data already in the file.

Thanks,

Naveed

Comment: To append to a file you'd have to retrieve the file, append your data, and upload the altered file. This is how FTP works, it's designed for transfering files it's not a fileserving application with normal file access semantics.

Comment: @Steve: Actually FTP does have the "APPE" (Append) Command, although it's debatable how widely supported that particular command is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps u can implement this logic for your FTP client...

1. Create flag "Updated=false"
2. Download this file locally
3. Change it by your custom logic
4. Upload this file with other name to the server
5. Rename old file
6. Give correct name for the new file
7. Delete old file
8. Mark "Updated=true" otherwise rollback name for the Server file

NOTE: U have to keep all protocol at the FTP-client.

---

UPDATES:

U can try to use some open source code to develop your FTP client, ie [C# FTP Client Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10968/C-FTP-Client-Library)

Comment: there is also the built in [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)